# Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventvalidation =”true” %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, sharepoint-2013

I am getting the below detailed error:

Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventvalidation =”true” %> in a page. For security purpose, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server that originally rendered them.

I am having a webpart page with a webpart where i do have a UPdatePanel and a button Upon Button click i  am getting this error.

the same package(wsp) which we are using in one of our environment is working fine and the same is not working in another environment.

Help in this is highly appreciable.

Comment: More info on what is in the UpdatePanel might help.  Is there a drop down list/select element?  Are you using client side javascript to dynamically add choices to a DDL/select/radio or something like that?

Comment: As mentioned by @eol, if you are updating controls that are data bound from the server side, such as a drop down list, and then adding items to the control using JavaScript, you will get such errors. However, since you are using an update panel, you can trigger an update of the Update Panel as described [here](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx). More information, or actual code will be helpful.

Comment: can you please put some code that will allow us to understand your question better

Comment: Are you triggering event manuaaly through javascript for the control in updatepanel? Or Have you generated button dynamically at client side and trying to click? Viewstate is not matching to it is giving this error.

Answer (score 2):

Without code it will be incredibly difficult to diagnose your issue.

You mentioned that your utilizing an *Update Panel*, which in essence will automatically store your page in memory, then it will render the proper *Ajax* to hide the *Postback*.  The [Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) basically warns you when you use the `EnableEventValidation` with Client-Side modification.

> If you write client script that changes a control in the client at run
>   time, you might have to use the RegisterForEventValidation method in
>   order to avoid false event validation errors.

Also if you initialize out of your `web.config` and directly in code, you should ensure that you call the validation before the page has been initialized.  So I would potentially use:

```
protected void Page_PreInit()
{
     // Before Page Initialization
}
```

Which would potentially eliminate any errors from the front-end, without code can't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok without some code to go on I'll fire some rounds off into the dark, I know next to nothing about SharePoint so I maybe missing something obvious here:

Firstly, check your environments, one may have a different web.config which has EnableEventValidation set to false.

Secondly on `Page_Load` are you doing any `DataBind`?  Depending on whatever your code is doing you may need make sure it's not binding on PostBack - or if it is already; try binding on PostBack.

Thirdly; any html or < > characters being included anywhere in the form? Also line breaks in data (my memory is a bit hazy on this one) I seem to remember, something like:

```
<option value="
my value
">select this</option>
```

Could cause it too. So doing a `Trim()` on data is recommended.

Lastly: Tag bleed out, check none of your tags are unclosed, something like `<span <asp:TextBox [...] />` this could be the cause too.

Answer (score 0):

**add EnableEventValidation="false" in page directive**

```
  <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```